# Fastlane - How to get version of podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fastlane

I want to include version of podspec to slack message in fastlane. How to get version of podspec from podfile?

*Fastfile* file

```
version = get_version_number_from_plist(scheme:ENV['TEST_SCHEME_NAME'])
build_number = get_build_number_from_plist(scheme:ENV['TEST_SCHEME_NAME'])
core_version = ??? -> version of MySDKCore

slack(message: "Released #{version}_#{build_number} app with #{core_version} core version")
```

*Podfile* file

```
pod 'MySDKCore', '1.2.3'
```

How to get version of podspec from podfile in fastlane?

Answer (score 0):

read the podfile and extract the version with Regular Expressions. we are using Fastlane.swift and doing this like this directly from the `.podspec`:

```
func extractVersion(in text: String) throws -> String? {
    return try extract(in: text, with: "version[ ]*=[ ]*\\\"([0-9\\.]*[a-zA-Z-]*)\\\"")
}
```

the parameters `text` is the content of the `.podspec` file. our version format is something like `1.1.1-subproject-name`